# Extract HTML attribute using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

This is what i currently have in my XLST. I want to extract the height of 117 from the html and use the variable instead of the value in the XSLT, I want to make the xslt generic so it would replace all Row_117 with Row_VARIABLE?

```
 <!-- Row_117px height -->
<xsl:template name="Row_117" match="xhtml:table[@class='Row_117']">
<table width="600" height="117" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth">
  <tr>
    <td>
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
        <![CDATA[  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              <table width="600" height="117" align="center">
                 <tr>
                   <td width="300">
        <![endif]--> ]]>
     </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, you have used `Row_117` in several places, you have named that template that way and you have used it as a string literal. You can't have generic or variable template names. As for replacing the `@class='Row_117'` check with a generic check, which version of XSLT do you use and what kind of criteria do you want to check? And if you want help to "extract HTML attribute" then show your HTML first.

Comment: We're using version 1.0. I want the XSLT to read in the height of a html table (which has a specific class on it) and then use that height as row_height rather than specifically specifying the height, hope that makes sense?